# How to make a function add to another function, whenever it is called?

Tags: java, string, function

Wasn't sure how to word this, but -

I have two functions. One is called CALC, and the other is CALCMethod.

In CALC, I want to make it so that it contains the result of 10 * 60 + 5. I want to make it so that, everytime I call the function CALCMethod in CALC, it will add 4 to the result in CALC.

How would I do this?

Here is my code so far.

```
public void CALCMethod( ) 
{ 
  
}
public int CALC( )
{
  return 10 * 60 + 5;
}
```

Basic yes, and sorry I can't think of how to word it better.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "everytime I call the function CALCMethod in CALC..." What if you call `CALCMethod` somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have CALCMethod take an int argument and return that int + 4. then you can call it once or with a loop however many times you like.

```
public int CALCMethod(int i) {
    return i + 4;
}
```

then inside CALC:

```
public int CALC() {
   return CALCMethod(10 * 60 + 5);
}
```

And with a loop:

```
public int CALC() {
   int number = 10 * 60 + 5;
   for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
       CALCMethod(number);
   }
   return number;
   
}
```